# Show google map in web view on monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

Here is the think... I have a base activity that derives from Activity and in one of my derived activities i need to show a google map with my current location. If i was not using this base activity i will derive my activity from map activity and use the com.google.android.maps.MapView Map control. But as i don't i can't...

So i tried to derive my base class with map activity but even this way it does't work i still have the same exception

> Android.Views.InflateException: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView

So, i want to display a map in a web view, but i just want to show the map, no google toolbars and so on... i look in the web to find a way to do it and i found some links, one of them is [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3) that i've liked a lot  but i don't know how to use the javascript. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So the URL that you are loading in your WebView in the sample is most likely: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html

This html page contains that JavaScript that is shown at the bottom of the sample you linked to. You will like to have that in your application as an asset or on your server so that it can be easily modified.

The source of that html is:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Simple V3 Map for Android</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var map;

  function initialize() {

    var latitude = 0;
    var longitude = 0;

    if (window.android){
      latitude = window.android.getLatitude();
      longitude = window.android.getLongitude();
    }

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function centerAt(latitude, longitude){
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);  
    map.panTo(myLatlng);
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Since this uses the normal Google Maps JavaScript API you can disable the defaultUI easily by adding this to the `myOptions` array:

```
disableDefaultUI: true,
```

Just like the docs say here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults